# Image Border Problems

Tags: css

I am have a little CSS issue if anyone can help please.

The attached image shows the sliced area I want to use as a background image to the bottom of a div. I have tried this to no avail.

I have also tried using it as a border-image just for the bottom of the page - but could not seem to get that to work. As this uses gradient in the CSS can anyone tell me how to do it in the existing #main div rather than adding a spare div underneath (with no content- naughty).

Help as always appreciated.

http://plusonetesting.co.uk/creative/

Ah was trying to add an image but it wont let me so have put the image here

http://plusonetesting.co.uk/creative/screen.jpg

G

Comment: could you perhaps give us the relevant css?

Comment: You could just do a `box-shadow`...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a linear-gradient for a background, using px values instead of the more common %.

http://jsfiddle.net/byZPb/

```
#main{
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(241,0,105) 5px, rgb(255,27,137) 10px, rgb(40,153,153) 20px);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(241,0,105) 5px, rgb(255,27,137) 10px, rgb(40,153,153) 20px);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(241,0,105) 5px, rgb(255,27,137) 10px, rgb(40,153,153) 20px);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(241,0,105) 5px, rgb(255,27,137) 10px, rgb(40,153,153) 20px);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(241,0,105) 5px, rgb(255,27,137) 10px, rgb(40,153,153) 20px);
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect with `box-shadow`: http://jsfiddle.net/YxVEy/

```
#one{
    height:200px;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%,#ddd 100%);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
#two{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    background:#def;
    z-index:-1;
    box-shadow:0 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
}
```

​`position:relative;z-index:-1;` allows `#two` to be overlayed by the box-shadow of `one`.